# how to get list of Begin and end block line number in plsql code using java code or any other solution

Tags: plsql

Example:
Below is the plsql code

BEGIN
BEGIN
END
END

OUTPUT should be (1,4) and (2,3)

I need to check for some lines once i got these index of begin and end block

Comment: What have you tried?  Marking this as plsql is not really correct seeing as that is not the language used to solve the problem, so maybe include java to if this is what you intend to use.  Simplest method would be to have a counter which increases each time you hit BEGIN and reduces each time you hit END.  Of course the other big 'if' is to assume that whatever code you are parsing is actually complete and the correct number of BEGIN/END pairs are available :)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this will get you started..

```
create or replace procedure x as
begin
begin
null; --required for valid procedure
end;
end;
/

Procedure X compiled

select * 
from user_source
where name = 'X';

NAME                           TYPE               LINE TEXT                                              
------------------------------ ------------ ---------- --------------------------------------------------
X                              PROCEDURE             1 procedure x as                                    
X                              PROCEDURE             2 begin                                             
X                              PROCEDURE             3 begin                                             
X                              PROCEDURE             4 null; --required for valid procedure              
X                              PROCEDURE             5 end;                                              
X                              PROCEDURE             6 end;                                              

6 rows selected.
```